# Google Cloud Platform running Spark throwing error - Database 'default' not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-bigquery

I am running a migration project to move code from old platform to Google Cloud Platform. The code is written in Java and we use Spark to run queries and other data transformations on Hive. After migration, all that code is replaced to run on Google BigQuery.

Now on to the actual problem. In one place this line of code is executed:

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn(columnName, org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF("randomKeyLong", dataFrame.col("delete")));
```

The error on GCP when this job runs is below and stacktrace points to the above line of code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'default' not found;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.functionExists(SessionCatalog.scala:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.functionExists(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:175)
...
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1312)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumns(Dataset.scala:2197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumn(Dataset.scala:2164)
...
```

Funny part is that sometimes this job runs without an error, and sometimes it throws an error. We are not running any query which may accidentally refer to the 'default' database.

The UDF is just to encrypt the value of this column using a custom class. The corresponding code is:

```
UDF1<Long, String> LongPeopleKeyRandomUDF = new UDF1<Long, String>() {
    public String call(Long key) {
        Encrypt udf = new Encrypt(); // Custom class
        return "people.key." + udf.Encriptar(Integer.toString(key.intValue()));
    }
};
```

We've been stuck on this for a while now, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your java code ? So I can investigate further.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes could you be a little more specific in terms of the code blocks/pieces you need as I am not at liberty to share code?

Comment: where you define the SparkSession. Also, did you configure a .xml for the Hive access?

Comment: It seems to be more of a cluster issue, and when we re-deployed the cluster and other infra the error went away.

Comment: How do you run Spark job? I.e. what Spark cluster do you use?